# It is only displaying one option in the drop down menu

Tags: php, mysqli

I have code below where the user types in a "Course", then it will display the relevant modules which belongs to that particular course and then it will display a drop down menu which belongs to the selected module.

The problem is that it only displays one session in the drop down menu which belongs to the module, even though there are a many sessions under that particular module.

For example is below is the database "Session" Table:

Session Table:

```
SessionId SessionDate SessionTime ModuleId
AAA       2012-10-19  09:00:00    CHI2513
AFD       2012-10-29  10:00:00    CHI2513
TPP       2012-09-11  09:00:00    CHI2513
NUM       2012-05-03  11:00:00    CHI2513
```

Then when the user selects Module "CHI2513" from the Module drop down menu, then in the Session drop down menu it should display the following option:

Session Drop Down menu:

```
AAA       2012-10-19  09:00:00
AFD       2012-10-29  10:00:00
TPP       2012-09-11  09:00:00
NUM       2012-05-03  11:00:00
```

But instead it is only showing one session in the drop down menu like below:

Session Drop Down menu it is showing at moment:

```
TPP       2012-09-11  09:00:00
```

So how can I display ALL of the sessions in the drop down menu which are relevant to the selected module?

Below is the code:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = "
             SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
             c.CourseName,
             m.ModuleName
             FROM Course c
             INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
             JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
             WHERE
             (c.CourseId = ?)
             ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
            ";

$qrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$qrystmt->bind_param("s",$courseid);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$qrystmt->execute(); 

$qrystmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);

 $qrystmt->store_result();

$num = $qrystmt->num_rows();

if($num ==0){
    echo "<p>Sorry, No Course was found with this Course ID '$courseid'</p>";
} else { 

    $dataArray = array();

 while ( $qrystmt->fetch() ) { 
      // data array
      $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['CourseName'] = $dbCourseName; 
      $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['Modules'][$dbModuleId]['ModuleName'] = $dbModuleName; 
       // session data
      $_SESSION['idcourse'] = $dbCourseId;
      $_SESSION['namecourse'] = $dbCourseName;

}

 foreach ($dataArray as $courseId => $courseData) {

      $output = ""; 

      $output .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseId .  " - "  . $courseData['CourseName'] . "</p>";

   $moduleHTML = ""; 
   $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modulesDrop" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
        foreach ($courseData['Modules'] as $moduleId => $moduleData) {        

        $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$moduleId'>" . $moduleId . " - " .   
    $moduleData['ModuleName'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
  } 
        }
        $moduleHTML .= '</select>';

  echo $output;


    ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="modulesubmit" /></p>      
    </form> 



    <?php
}
}

$sessionnum = 0;

 if (isset($_POST['modulesubmit'])) {

     if($_REQUEST['modulesDrop']==''){

         echo "Please Select a Module from the Drop Down Menu Above";

     }
     else{  

 var_dump($_POST['modulesDrop']);

        $sessionquery = "
             SELECT SessionId, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
             FROM Session
             WHERE
             (ModuleId = ?)
             ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
            ";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modulesDrop']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

 $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

    $dataArraySession = array();

 while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) { 

 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSessionDate; 
 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime;

}

foreach ($dataArraySession as $sessionId => $sessionData) {



   $sessionHTML = ""; 
   $sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           
   $sessionHTML .= "<option value='$sessionId'>" . $sessionId . " - " . $sessionData['SessionDate']. " - " . $sessionData['SessionTime'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        

        }

   $sessionHTML .= '</select>';
}
 if ($sessionnum > 0) {

 ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Sessions: <?php echo $sessionHTML; ?><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="sesionsubmit" /></p>      
    </form>       

<?php

}
else {
 echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Sessions under this Module</p>";
}

}


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well You are applying an `ORDER BY` clause to your query, which says to me the TPP row of data is the last bit of data output by the query. Which then in turn tells me to look at your loop thats building the HTML output.

In that loop you have `$output = "";` in the begining of the loop. Which is reseting it every pass of the loop. And you do the same thing with `$moduleHTML`

So I can see how `$output` being echoed at the end of every loop through will show the results correctly. But in the form below your calling `modelHTML` which for every loop through the results is resetting thus negating the concept of `.=` to append to it. What you should do is put

`$moduleHTML` outside of your foreach so its initially defined there, then keep everything else the same.

eg:

```
$moduleHTML = "";
foreach(....){.....}
```

instead of

```
foreach(....){....$moduleHTML = "";....}
```

What its doing currently is only saving the last run so to speak through the loop for output in your widget, module, form, whatever..

Comment: Hi, I moved $moduleHTML outside the loop like you said but it is still displaying only one sessin in the drop down menu, do I need to move $sessionHTML outside its loop as well?

Comment: If I move the $sessionHTML = ""; outside its loop, then I get numerous drop down menus, each session drop down menu all having its own session in its drop down

Comment: Yes along with the initial `<select>..` part of it, essentially in that case all you want is maybe the `<option>` parts appending to the string overall. In general you are right up the alley of where you need to be, and want to end up. Its just going to take a little play from where you are currently to get it just right. General rule of thumb is if your going to build out a string via a loop you start it empty or in your case with the tags that can only be called once in an element, then append from there, then at the end of the loop outside of it again finish off the string with `</select>`

Comment: remember all the loop is doing is litterally processing the same set of functions over and over again, repetition. So only what needs to be repeated should be in the loop

Comment: Ok I will work it out, thanks for the advice of the loops, this helps me understand loops a lot better as I am weak with loops :)

Comment: Got it working, like you said move the select and the first option "Please Select" option for the $sessionHTML outside the loop and it worked fine. Thank You :)

Comment: No problem, feel free to find me around if ya need some more help sometime. stack@chrishacia.com if ya'd like to shoot an email sometime